# Update/Insert into table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have to update table on SQL Server but first i have to check for existing data in table so if data is there update it, if not make a new insert:

```
cmd_sql.CommandText = " SELECT BrDok as id_dok " +
                      " FROM ordersstavke " +
                      " WHERE SifParFil = '" + rw_mat["sifskl_kor"] + "'" +
                      " AND DokumentTip = '" + rw_mat["vrst_dok"] + "'";

MySqlDataAdapter sql_adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd_sql);
DataSet dt_dok = new DataSet("DOK_MAT_EXCHANGE");
sql_adapter.Fill(dt_dok);

if (dt_dok.Tables["DOK_MAT_EXCHANGE"].Rows.Count == 0)
{
   myQuery = " INSERT INTO ordersstavke (BrDok, DocumentTip, SifParFil) " +
             " VALUES ('" + rw_mat["brdok"] + "', '" +
                            rw_mat["vrst_dok"] + "', '" +
                            rw_mat["sifskl_kor"] + "')";
}
else
{
    UPDATE DATA
}
```

But I have an error in the code, the error is here if (`dt_dok.Tables["DOK_MAT_EXCHANGE"].Rows.Count == 0`)

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The problem is in this if statement...

Comment: Please Please Please switch from Dynamic SQL to Parameterized Queries if you aren't going to use full blown Stored Procedures.  You are exposing yourself to SQL Injection attacks whenever you use Dynamic SQL.  Straight from the horse's mouth:   http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks guys, I wrote it like this

```
if (ds_dok.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        myQuery = " INSERT INTO ordersstavke (BrDok, " +
                                  " SifParFil) " +
                                  " VALUES ('" + rw_mat["brdok"] + "', '" +
                                                 rw_mat["sifskl_kor"] + "')";
                    }
                    else if (ds_dok.Tables[0].Rows.Count >= 1)
                    {

                        myQuery = "UPDATE ordersstavke " +
                                  "SET BrDok = '" + rw_mat["brdok"] + "', " +
                                  "SifParFil = '" + rw_mat["sifskl_kor"] + "', " +
                                  "WHERE BrDok = " + ds_dok.Tables["ordersstavke"].Rows[0]["BrDok"].ToString() + "'";

                    }
```

But there is a small problem in the section update: s_dok.Tables["ordersstavke"].Rows[0]["BrDok"].ToString(), here it give me that loving error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Maybe the update on MySQL goes on different way, I'm referencing on example on sql server and there update goes differently

Answer (score 4):

`DOK_MAT_EXCHANGE` is the name of the `DataSet`, not of the first table.

You should test with

```
if (dt_dok.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
```

Also, I think is better to use a syntax like this to discover how many records are presents

```
cmd_sql.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(BrDok) as id_dok " +
                      " FROM ordersstavke " +                         
                      " WHERE SifParFil = ?p1 " +                         
                      " AND DokumentTip = ?p2";   
cmd_sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("?p1", rw_mat["sifskl_kor"] );
cmd_sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("?p2", rw_mat["vrst_dok"] );
int rowCount = (Int32)cmd_sql.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
DataSet dt_dok = new DataSet("DOK_MAT_EXCHANGE");
```

to

```
DataSet dt_dok = new DataSet("ordersstavke ");
```

and

```
if (dt_dok.Tables["DOK_MAT_EXCHANGE"].Rows.Count == 0)
```

to

```
if (dt_dok.Tables["ordersstavke "].Rows.Count == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the first table via the dataset name is incorrect, that's for setting the XML.

Instead use

```
dt_dok.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

That being said, you're better off writing this as a single SQL statement instead of a separate select && insert.  This way you're not going to the DB multiple times.

```
var sql = @"if exists(select * from ordersstavke where SifParFil = ? and DokumentTip = ?)
then 
 -- do insert statement
else
 -- do update
end if";
```

This might also be better done with a stored proc, so you don't have as much SQL code in C#.  It's easier to manage multiple operations that way.

And for crying out loud, use `SqlParameters`, not string concatenation! That's just asking for trouble!